# How to get the file path of current file through a function defined in another file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, path

consider there are two files

```
   ./file2.js
    function scriptpath()
    return __filename

   ./file1.js
    var path = file2.scriptpath()
    console.log(path)  //returns absolute path of file2.js but not file1.js
```

I'm expecting to get the absolute path of file(file1.js) from where it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need the path of file1.js inside file2.js. You could use this:

```
./file2.js
function scriptpath(callername)
return callername

./file1.js
var path = file2.scriptpath(__filename)
console.log(path)  //returns path of file1.js
```